# Publishing fails during 'committing deployment': cannot execute SQL Query

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

I've been bouncing my head against this issue for the last couple of hours now and I can't seem to come up with a solution. I'm trying to setup a Tridion Install SP1 HR1, with SQL database.

As far as I can tell, the http transport protocol *should* work, as changing anything related to this protocol still comes up with the same error.

As soon as a page (pretty simple one, too) hits 'committing deployment', the publish fails due to the following error:

```
2013-01-14 16:49:22,351 ERROR DeployPipelineExecutor - Original stacktrace for transaction: tcm:0-16-66560
com.tridion.deployer.ProcessingException: Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-16-66560, org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query, org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.PreCommitPhase.handleFailure(PreCommitPhase.java:120) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.PreCommitPhase.execute(PreCommitPhase.java:101) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runMainExecutePhase(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:186) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.doExecute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:97) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.execute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:61) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.handleDeployPackage(TransactionManager.java:80) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.queue.QueueLocationHandler$1.run(QueueLocationHandler.java:176) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_38]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_38]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_38]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_38]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_38]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_38]
```

My storage_conf.xml looks like this

```
<Storages><Storage Type="persistence" Id="sqlserver" dialect="MSSQL" Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory">
            <Pool Type="jdbc" Size="5" MonitorInterval="60" IdleTimeout="120" CheckoutTimeout="120" />
            <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
                <Property Name="serverName" Value="T2011-DEV" />
                <Property Name="portNumber" Value="1433" />
                <Property Name="databaseName" Value="Tridion_cm" />
                <Property Name="user" Value="secret" />
                <Property Name="password" Value="secret" />
            </DataSource>
        </Storage>

        <!--            
            Configuration example for using filesystem as data storage. 
        -->
        <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="iisFile">
            <Root Path="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\staging.dev" />
        </Storage>
    </Storages>    </Global>
<!-- If no item type mappings are defined within ItemTypes or if storages on a lower level do not exist then the storage defined by defaultStorageId attribute will be used.
     If storage defined by defaultStorageId does not exist then exception will be thrown. -->
<ItemTypes defaultStorageId="sqlserver" cached="false">
    <Item typeMapping="Page" cached="false" storageId="iisFile"/>
    <Item typeMapping="Binary" storageId="iisFile" cached="false"/>
</ItemTypes>
```

I've had some interesting issues with the Java install before, but got around that. I've even installed the .jar files from another machine that had a proper HTTP transport connection going and installed these over the ones I had, but that didn't work either. I also included the -assumingly- correct SQLDB4 -jar file. I have no clue what is causing this. The database connection seems to exist just fine as altering the logins into bogus returns a "no connection possible" or somesuch error.

any help would be fantastic.

### EDIT

After Sea_gull said to enable root logging a lot of errors turned up.  This is quite a list, but here are the most important parts:

`013-01-14 19:28:01,578 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction tcm:0-17-66560.
2013-01-14 19:28:01,579 INFO  PreCommitPhase - Executing workers for transaction: tcm:0-17-66560 with 4 Workers
2013-01-14 19:28:01,579 DEBUG PreCommitPhase - Executing worker com.tridion.storage.deploy.workers.DynamicLinkInfoTrackingWorker@76612ef6 this is worker 1 of: 4
2013-01-14 19:28:01,580 DEBUG StorageManagerFactory - Loading a non cached DAO for publicationId/typeMapping/itemExtension: 12 / DynamicLinkInfo / null
2013-01-14 19:28:01,580 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'sqlserverEntityManagerFactory'
2013-01-14 19:28:01,580 DEBUG SessionImpl - opened session at timestamp: 13581880815
2013-01-14 19:28:01,580 DEBUG JDBCTransaction - begin
2013-01-14 19:28:01,581 DEBUG ConnectionManager - opening JDBC connection
2013-01-14 19:28:01,581 DEBUG JDBCTransaction - current autocommit status: true
2013-01-14 19:28:01,581 DEBUG JDBCTransaction - disabling autocommit
2013-01-14 19:28:01,582 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'JPADynamicLinkDAO'
2013-01-14 19:28:01,583 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'JPADynamicLinkDAO'
2013-01-14 19:28:01,583 DEBUG JPADAOFactory - Loaded DAO with type: JPADynamicLinkDAO inside transaction: tcm:0-17-66560
2013-01-14 19:28:01,583 DEBUG StorageManagerFactory - Wrapping DAO's, currently 0 wrappers installed
2013-01-14 19:28:01,583 DEBUG JPADynamicLinkDAO - Storing dynamic links from TCMURI tcm:12-88-64
2013-01-14 19:28:01,583 DEBUG JPADynamicLinkDAO - Removing dynamic links with source TCMURI tcm:12-88-64
2013-01-14 19:28:01,584 DEBUG AbstractBatcher - about to open PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0)
2013-01-14 19:28:01,584 DEBUG SQL - delete from DYNAMIC_LINKS where SRC_PUB_ID=? and SRC_ITEM_ID=? and SRC_ITEM_TYPE=?
2013-01-14 19:28:01,585 DEBUG AbstractBatcher - about to close PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 1, globally: 1)
2013-01-14 19:28:01,587 DEBUG JDBCExceptionReporter - could not execute update query [delete from DYNAMIC_LINKS where SRC_PUB_ID=? and SRC_ITEM_ID=? and SRC_ITEM_TYPE=?]
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'DYNAMIC_LINKS'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216) ~[sqljdbc4.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515) ~[sqljdbc4.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:404) ~[sqljdbc4.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:350) ~[sqljdbc4.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696) ~[sqljdbc4.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715) ~[sqljdbc4.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180) ~[sqljdbc4.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155) ~[sqljdbc4.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:314) ~[sqljdbc4.jar:na]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:102) ~[commons-dbcp.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:102) ~[commons-dbcp.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.exec.BasicExecutor.execute(BasicExecutor.java:101) ~[hibernate-core.jar:3.3.2.GA]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.executeUpdate(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:421) [hibernate-core.jar:3.3.2.GA]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(HQLQueryPlan.java:283) [hibernate-core.jar:3.3.2.GA]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.executeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1169) [hibernate-core.jar:3.3.2.GA]
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:117) [hibernate-core.jar:3.3.2.GA]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:51) [hibernate-entitymanager.jar:3.4.0.GA]
    at com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPABaseDAO.executeQueryUpdate(JPABaseDAO.java:304) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADynamicLinkDAO.remove(JPADynamicLinkDAO.java:104) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADynamicLinkDAO.store(JPADynamicLinkDAO.java:43) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.deploy.workers.DynamicLinkInfoTrackingWorker.doDeploy(DynamicLinkInfoTrackingWorker.java:52) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.model.transaction.TransactionLogItemWorker.doWork(TransactionLogItemWorker.java:27) [cd_model.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.PreCommitPhase.runPrepare(PreCommitPhase.java:143) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.PreCommitPhase.execute(PreCommitPhase.java:91) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runMainExecutePhase(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:186) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.doExecute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:97) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.execute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:61) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.handleDeployPackage(TransactionManager.java:80) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.queue.QueueLocationHandler$1.run(QueueLocationHandler.java:176) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_38]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_38]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_38]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_38]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_38]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_38]
2013-01-14 19:28:01,588 WARN  JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 208, SQLState: S0002
2013-01-14 19:28:01,588 ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter - Invalid object name 'DYNAMIC_LINKS'.
2013-01-14 19:28:01,588 DEBUG AbstractEntityManagerImpl - mark transaction for rollback
2013-01-14 19:28:01,588 DEBUG DynamicLinkInfoTrackingWorker - Error looking up the dynamic link dao
2013-01-14 19:28:01,588 DEBUG PreCommitPhase - Executing worker: com.tridion.storage.deploy.workers.DynamicLinkInfoTrackingWorker@76612ef6 took: 9
2013-01-14 19:28:01,588 DEBUG PreCommitPhase - Executing worker com.tridion.storage.deploy.workers.ReferenceEntryWorker@66525531 this is worker 2 of: 4
2013-01-14 19:28:01,589 DEBUG StorageManagerFactory - Loading a non cached DAO for publicationId/typeMapping/itemExtension: 12 / Reference / null
2013-01-14 19:28:01,589 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'JPAReferenceEntryDAO'
2013-01-14 19:28:01,589 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'JPAReferenceEntryDAO'
2013-01-14 19:28:01,589 DEBUG JPADAOFactory - Loaded DAO with type: JPAReferenceEntryDAO inside transaction: tcm:0-17-66560
2013-01-14 19:28:01,589 DEBUG StorageManagerFactory - Wrapping DAO's, currently 0 wrappers installed
2013-01-14 19:28:01,590 DEBUG AbstractBatcher - about to open PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0)
2013-01-14 19:28:01,590 DEBUG SQL - select referencee0_.REFERENCING_URI as REFERENC1_20_, referencee0_.REFERENCED_URI as REFERENCED2_20_, referencee0_.PUBLICATION_ID as PUBLICAT3_20_ from REFERENCE_ENTRIES referencee0_ where referencee0_.PUBLICATION_ID=? and referencee0_.REFERENCING_URI=?
2013-01-14 19:28:01,592 DEBUG AbstractBatcher - about to close PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 1, globally: 1)
2013-01-14 19:28:01,594 DEBUG JDBCExceptionReporter - could not execute query [select referencee0_.REFERENCING_URI as REFERENC1_20_, referencee0_.REFERENCED_URI as REFERENCED2_20_, referencee0_.PUBLICATION_ID as PUBLICAT3_20_ from REFERENCE_ENTRIES referencee0_ where referencee0_.PUBLICATION_ID=? and referencee0_.REFERENCING_URI=?]
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'REFERENCE_ENTRIES'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216) ~[sqljdbc4.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515) ~[sqljdbc4.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:404) ~[sqljdbc4.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:350) ~[sqljdbc4.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696) ~[sqljdbc4.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715) ~[sqljdbc4.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180) ~[sqljdbc4.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155) ~[sqljdbc4.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:285) ~[sqljdbc4.jar:na]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:93) ~[commons-dbcp.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:93) ~[commons-dbcp.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208) ~[hibernate-core.jar:3.3.2.GA]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1812) [hibernate-core.jar:3.3.2.GA]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:697) [hibernate-core.jar:3.3.2.GA]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259) [hibernate-core.jar:3.3.2.GA]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2232) [hibernate-core.jar:3.3.2.GA]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2129) [hibernate-core.jar:3.3.2.GA]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2124) [hibernate-core.jar:3.3.2.GA]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:401) [hibernate-core.jar:3.3.2.GA]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:363) [hibernate-core.jar:3.3.2.GA]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196) [hibernate-core.jar:3.3.2.GA]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1149) [hibernate-core.jar:3.3.2.GA]
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102) [hibernate-core.jar:3.3.2.GA]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:67) [hibernate-entitymanager.jar:3.4.0.GA]
    at com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPABaseDAO.executeQueryListResult(JPABaseDAO.java:266) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPABaseDAO.executeQueryListResult(JPABaseDAO.java:234) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPABaseDAO.executeQueryListResult(JPABaseDAO.java:217) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPAReferenceEntryDAO.findByReferencingURI(JPAReferenceEntryDAO.java:80) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.services.ReferenceCounter.replaceReferences(ReferenceCounter.java:160) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.deploy.workers.ReferenceEntryWorker.doDeploy(ReferenceEntryWorker.java:61) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.model.transaction.TransactionLogItemWorker.doWork(TransactionLogItemWorker.java:27) [cd_model.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.PreCommitPhase.runPrepare(PreCommitPhase.java:143) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.PreCommitPhase.execute(PreCommitPhase.java:91) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runMainExecutePhase(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:186) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.doExecute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:97) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.execute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:61) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.handleDeployPackage(TransactionManager.java:80) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.queue.QueueLocationHandler$1.run(QueueLocationHandler.java:176) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_38]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_38]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_38]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_38]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_38]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_38]
2013-01-14 19:28:01,594 WARN  JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 208, SQLState: S0002
2013-01-14 19:28:01,594 ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter - Invalid object name 'REFERENCE_ENTRIES'.
2013-01-14 19:28:01,594 DEBUG AbstractEntityManagerImpl - mark transaction for rollback
2013-01-14 19:28:01,595 WARN  PreCommitPhase - Failed to Prepare: tcm:0-17-66560 error: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
2013-01-14 19:28:01,595 INFO  StorageManagerFactory - Rolling back storage transaction: tcm:0-17-66560
2013-01-14 19:28:01,595 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Nothing to roll back for transaction tcm:0-17-66560.
2013-01-14 19:28:01,595 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Cleaning up transaction tcm:0-17-66560.
2013-01-14 19:28:01,595 DEBUG JDBCTransaction - rollback
2013-01-14 19:28:01,596 DEBUG JDBCTransaction - re-enabling autocommit
2013-01-14 19:28:01,596 DEBUG JDBCTransaction - rolled back JDBC Connection
2013-01-14 19:28:01,596 DEBUG ConnectionManager - aggressively releasing JDBC connection
2013-01-14 19:28:01,596 DEBUG ConnectionManager - releasing JDBC connection [ (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0) (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)]
2013-01-14 19:28:01,597 WARN  DeployPipelineExecutor - Phase: Deployment Prepare Commit Phase failure message: Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-17-66560, org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query, org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query for transaction: tcm:0-17-66560
2013-01-14 19:28:01,597 DEBUG DeployPipelineExecutor - Failure in Phase: Deployment Prepare Commit Phase attempt: 11 for transaction: tcm:0-17-66560
2013-01-14 19:28:01,597 ERROR DeployPipelineExecutor - Final attempt in Phase: Deployment Prepare Commit Phase failed for transaction: tcm:0-17-66560
2013-01-14 19:28:01,598 ERROR DeployPipelineExecutor - Original stacktrace for transaction: tcm:0-17-66560
com.tridion.deployer.ProcessingException: Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-17-66560, org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query, org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.PreCommitPhase.handleFailure(PreCommitPhase.java:120) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.PreCommitPhase.execute(PreCommitPhase.java:101) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runMainExecutePhase(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:186) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.doExecute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:97) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.execute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:61) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.handleDeployPackage(TransactionManager.java:80) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.queue.QueueLocationHandler$1.run(QueueLocationHandler.java:176) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_38]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_38]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_38]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_38]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_38]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_38]
2013-01-14 19:28:01,598 INFO  TransactionPersistence - Removing deployment transaction information: tcm:0-17-66560
2013-01-14 19:28:01,601 ERROR DeployPipelineExecutor - Unable to start processing deployment package with transactionId: tcm:0-17-66560
2013-01-14 19:28:01,606 DEBUG DeployPipelineExecutor - Checking if transaction is completed: tcm:0-17-66560 is true
2013-01-14 19:28:01,606 INFO  DeployPipelineExecutor - Transaction is completed: tcm:0-17-66560
2013-01-14 19:28:01,616 INFO  DeployPipelineExecutor - Finished executing deployment pipeline for: tcm:0-17-66560 in 30231 ms.
2013-01-14 19:28:01,616 INFO  TransactionManager - Cleaning up Deployment package for transaction: tcm:0-17-66560 and type: CONTENT
2013-01-14 19:28:01,621 INFO  TransactionManager - Finished handling of Deployment package: tcm:0-17-66560 with type: CONTENT
2013-01-14 19:28:01,622 DEBUG QueueLocationHandler - Removing exclusive lock on Deployment package: tcm:0-17-66560 with type: CONTENT.
2013-01-14 19:28:02,664 DEBUG HttpUploadReceiver - transactionId parameter contained an invalid TCM URI string: meta.xml, processing as normal file request
2013-01-14 19:28:02,665 INFO  HttpUploadReceiver - File found at C:\tridion\incoming\meta.xml for meta.xml
2013-01-14 19:28:02,699 DEBUG HttpUploadReceiver - transactionId parameter contained an invalid TCM URI string: tcm_0-17-66560.state.xml, processing as normal file request
2013-01-14 19:28:02,700 INFO  HttpUploadReceiver - File found at C:\tridion\incoming\tcm_0-17-66560.state.xml for tcm_0-17-66560.state.xml
2013-01-14 19:28:02,700 INFO  HttpUploadReceiver - Removed file at C:\tridion\incoming\tcm_0-17-66560.state.xml`

there are so many points of interest here I'm not even sure where it goes wrong...

Comment: Hi there. Can you please try to enable root logging (<root level="DEBUG">) or Hibernate logging? Then check exactly what's the Hibernate stack-trace generated. This should give you more info.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me. However, I don't really know what you mean - I'm unsure where to enable these logging options and my Tridion logs are already on the maximum (DEBUG) level...

Comment: In your logback.xml you have at the end a section like this: <root level="OFF"> <appender-ref ref="rollingCoreLog"/> </root>. Change that OFF to DEBUG. As an consequence, you will get logging from a lot of third party libraries inside your cd_core.log.

Comment: A lot of interesting info turned up. I will update my post shortly.

Comment: Based on the exception log error message, the table DYNAMIC_LINK does not exist. Did you configure it to the correct DB? Looking at your storage conf 'databaseName'  property has "Tridion_cm". Typically we name CMS db like this and cda db will be something like broker db etc. please double check the property dstabaseName and make due you have all broker tables in this db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Ram G already mentioned, this is a problem with the used database which seems to miss tables used by Content Delivery. You're probably using a CM database instead of a CD one. Please make sure that your database is correctly created and retry your test.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Apparantly I completely misreferenced the Broker Database. A very amateurish error, but I'm glad the solution was pretty simple. Thanks all!